# Can't get the return value of dijit.form.DateTextBox formatted properly

Tags: date, dojo, format, locale

I can't get my return value from a dijit.form.DateTextBox formatted properly. I create the dijit like this:

```
this.inputValueParam = new dijit.form.DateTextBox({constraints: { datePattern : 'yyyy-MM-dd' }}).placeAt('paramTypeSelect', 'after');
```

and I call the value like this:

```
this.inputValueParam.get('value')
```

I always get a date like this: **wed dec 14 2011 00:00:00 gmt+0100 (cet)** but I want the date in the same format as it is showed: **14-12-2011**

I tried working with `{constraints: { datePattern : 'dd-MM-yyyy' }}` but this made no difference.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

This works for me:

```
dojo.date.locale.format(dateBox.value, {datePattern: "yyyy-MM-dd", selector: "date"})
```

It will output your date with the desired pattern

Little example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tvUaK/62/)

Comment: Isn't this just postprocessing the value? If I don't get you wrong, the value coming from the dateBox is still like wed dec 14 2011 00:00:00 gmt+0100 (cet) - or am I missing the point?